# Relative position of two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two lines:

$r:\begin{cases}x=t \\ y=2t+1\\z=t-2 \end {cases}$

and

$s:\begin{cases}x+2y-z=0 \\ 3x+y+z+1=0 \end {cases}$

I have to establish their relative position.

I have thought that $s=\{v: v \perp u_1\ \text{and } v \perp u_2\}$  ($u_1=(1,2, -1) \text { and } u_2=(3, 1, 1)$). And so I found the vector $w_1$ that spans *s*: $w_1=(-3, 4, 5)$.

If *r//s*, their vectors of direction have to be linearly dependents.

The vector of direction of *r* is $w_2=(1, 2, 1)$.

Well, $w_1 \text { and }$ $w_2$ aren't linearly dependent, so *r* and *s* aren't parallel.

But, if I try to solve this set: 
$\begin{cases}x=t \\ y=2t+1\\z=t-2\\x+2y-z=0 \\ 3x+y+z+1=0 \end{cases}$

I obtain no solutions exist" and so *r* seems parallel to *s*.. :/

Where and why am I wronging? :(

Thank you

Comment: Your $\,w_1\,$ does *not* span $\,s\,$ as it doesn't satisfy the second linear equation defining $\,s\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio I have solved the homogeneous linear system associated by *s*. I have obtained $x=(-3/4)y$ and $z=(5/4)y$. So assuming $y=b$, I have $x=(-3/4)b$, $y=b$, $z=(5/4)y$ and the space of solutions is spanned by $(-3/4, 1, 5/4)$. Multiplying for 4, I obtain $w_1$. What's wrong?

Comment: just substitute that value into the second equation and it *won't* satisfy it...! The mistake is that you *cannot* multiply the solution you obtained as the second equation is *not* linear: there is that $\,1\,$ there, see?

Comment: BTW, *neither* the vector $\,(-3/4\,,\,1\,,\,5/4)\,$ is a solution...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, let's restart.. :( You're right..  But I can't understand(!): vectors belonging to s are perpendicular to $u_1$ and $u_2$, isn't it? If I consider a generic v belonging to s, I have that scalar products between v and $u_1$ and between v and $u_2$ have to be 0. And so I have a set of two equations (my two conditions about inner product)... I solve it and.. what's wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly obtained the direction $w_1$ of the second line as a vector proportional to $=u_1\times u_2$, and correctly find that the two lines have no intersection.

But you forget that in 3-dimensional space, two lines can be neither parallel nor incident, the third possibility being that they are skew lines.

Comment: All right! Thanks a lot! :)